# Git problems pushing local to server

Tags: git

I have a local git repo that has been initialized with:
$git init

I want to push this to a development server.

This is de directory structure on the dev server:
ROOT/public_html
ROOT/public_html.git

Within public_html.git I've initialized a bare repo using:

```
$git init --bare
```

Then I've created a post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/path/to/public_html
```

On the local machine I've added the remote:

```
$git remote add development ssh://location/public_html.git
```

I then pushed the local repo to the remote using:

```
$git push development master
```

This all worked and I've got the message that the repo was successfuly pushed.

However the files are not copied to the work tree. No files exist in that directory.

using the command:
`sh /hooks/post-receive` to check whether or not the post-receive hook work will give me the message:
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

I've googled this error message, but the few pages that popup are not very helpful.

Changing the config file to:

```
[core]
bare = false 
worktree = /home/path/to/public_html/
```

will let me use git checkout -f which will copy files to the working directory, however pushing from local to development gives me this error:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

So ehm, I'm kinda stuck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables you set in post-receive script work only inside that script.

Your second approach won't work, because this is how git works.

If you really need to, then checkout explicitly from the local bare repository in your post-receive script. Don't set worktree.

Comment: The second method isn't the one I prefer, however it does help me get the files from the repo to the work tree. The problem is that pushing to the remote repo doesn't update the files in the work tree which is set in the post-receive HOOK. It shows the message: `fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`

Comment: again. do `git checkout` in post-receive.

Comment: And of course, once: `git clone public_html.git public_html`

Comment: I tried: `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/path/to/public_html git checkout` & `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/path/to/public_html git checkout -f`. Same error: `fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`

Comment: Ah wait, didn't saw your last message. Trying now!

Comment: I cloned the repo using `git clone public_html.git public_html`. This copied all files in the repo to public_html. After that I changed some files locally, pushed it to the git repo (`git push development`). Using `git log` in the public_html.git shows the commit. However the files are not in the public_html dir. Executing `sh hooks/post-receive` from the cli show the fatal again: `fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`

Comment: MAybe the contents of post-receive should be: `cd /home/path/to/public_html && git fetch && git checkout -f origin/master`

Comment: Or (without `public_html/.git`): `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/path/to/public_html git checkout -f master~0`